# iOS Regular Expression Understanding

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

Recently I will use NSRegularExpression to help me parse a website's source.

I found this example expression `@"(.*?)(<[^>]+>|\\Z)"`. Could any kind people help me out with the meaning of this pattern?

Comment: I would recommend basic research via a popular search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(.*?)(<[^>]+>|\Z)` - the first part `(.*?)` is non-greedy way of consuming characters, or in other words, consume the minimum possible number of characters until we reach the next part: `(<[^>]+>|\Z)`.

`(<[^>]+>|\Z)` - Here we have two parts, the first part is `<[^>]+>` - match to an expression that starts with `<` and has at least one character before the closing `>`. he `[^>]` means any character except `>` and the `+` means any number of characters >= 1.

The `|` is an "or" - which means that this matching group should match either the first part `<[^>]+>` or the second part `\Z` which means an end of a string.

Comment: Thank you, really detailed explanation! For one part, I did not understand throughly. [^>] what does this mean? because ^ means the  beginning, does it mean pattern like this "<>","<>>","<>>>" and no other patterns.

Comment: The `[^>]` means any character except `>` - I'll add it to the answer.